# Does the import & export keywords part of webpack or JS language?

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, export

I asking myself does the import&export parts of language or  simple keywords which webpack add to language?
Thanks.

Comment: js modules were added to javascript as part of ES6. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Thanks a lot,i had ununderstanding about this topic,i google it,but find nothing.

Answer (score 2):

`import` and `export` (JavaScript modules) are part of JavaScript, added in ES2015. However, browsers didn't support them until **very** recently, so Webpack (and others) handle them, converting them into RequireJS calls or similar when creating the JavaScript bundle for a project. (This is still handy even though browsers now have module support, because the bundle can be a single `.js` file with module resolution occurring internally, whereas browser support for modules is still very new and involves multiple requests. [That will change at some point.])

So the answer is kind of "both." They're part of JavaScript, *and* Webpack (and tools like it) handle them.

Comment: So,we can use modules whithout webpack or?We must compile all modern code,this is cristal clear for me,does the babel without webpack can compile modules?

Comment: @GoranIlic You can in current versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, yes. But for now, each module is its own file, which can be inefficient. Bundlers like Webpack and Browserify and such still play there, combining modules into bundles with a single file.

Comment: Thanks a lot and have a nice day (Y) .